# Is SCALA is a theoretical language?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Please correct me if am wrong ...

Scala introduces new paradigms like TypeTheory, Continuations, Monads and other computational theories.  Is Scala is becoming or more a theoretical language because most of papers, blogs talk about this and I comparatively see less code illustrations...

Comment: Becoming more theoretical than what?  Seeing less code illustrations than what?  In order to use comparatives, you need to mention two things that you're comparing!

Comment: prassee might mean an 'academic language', maybe?

Comment: yes 'academic language' is the term i should be used ....

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Type theory** is not a paradigm, that's like claiming Java is "theoretical" because it uses integer addition from "number theory"

**Continuations** are a mainstream feature of many languages: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation#Programming_language_support
They're already in the Java Servlet 3.0 specification (where they're known as suspended requests)

**Monads** are just a standard technique for composing functions, in languages that support functions as a first-class entity; including Lisp (e.g. Clojure), ML (e.g. F#), Haskell and Scala.

Although some languages offer syntactic sugar for dealing with Monads, there's nothing to prevent you from creating one in Java using SAM types in lieu of true functions.